# 'Value' binding doesn't work with optgroup in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I finally got optgroups to work with Knockout using this:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: $root.countries, value: selectedCountry">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children">
        <option data-bind="text: label"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This shows a list of all countries grouped by continent. But, I can't get the selectedCountry to work. What am I missing here?

For the record: selectedCountry is a property of 'user' (the country the user lives in). I loop over all users using this:

```
<tbody class="sortable user_div" data-bind="sortable: { data: form.users }">
     <!-- Here a <tr> and all form elements, including the <select> above -->
</tbody>
```

This works within the same `tbody` the `select` is in:

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: userName" /></td>
```

I'm accessing both userName and selectedCountry in the same way (as you can see). Both are properties of the User object. I'm 100% positive selectedCountry is the right property. When I switch userName and selectedCountry, I get the selectedCountry in the `<input type="text">`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmC3d/)**. Are you sure the `selectedCountry` property is correct? Also, could you provide a JSFiddle/modify mine to actually see the problem?

Comment: I can't get it to work in JSFiddle... Too much surrounding code. But the problem is that I'm already in a loop (see the <tbody> in the second code snippet). So I'm not referencing a selectedValue on the same level as you are in the example. I'm trying to accessing it within the 'user' I'm looping over. This works fine for other elements. I'll update my question to include a small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooooooh, I'm so stupid.

`<option data-bind="text: label"></option>` <-- there I'm not binding any value. So this was the solution:

`<option data-bind="text: label, value: label"></option>`